# Unit-testing code with a large number of interdependent conditions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm testing a set of output styler classes which style data before outputting it to an output interface. The behavior of each styler is dependent on up to 5 different conditions (at the moment, but a sixth is on the way) with regard to the object being outputted: isKey, isDefault, isEmpty, isReadOnly, isAccessible

So one styler might output nothing if it has readonly data, while another might show "access denied".

At the moment I am testing along these lines, but the tests are exploding as more conditions are added.

```
{
    //  isKey, isDefault, isEmpty, isReadOnly, isAccessible
    ValueOutputTester::TestConditions conditions = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    EXPECT_EQ(valueOutputTester(conditions), accessDeniedOutput);
}
{
    ValueOutputTester::TestConditions conditions = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    EXPECT_EQ(valueOutputTester(conditions), normalOutput);
}
{
    ValueOutputTester::TestConditions conditions = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
    EXPECT_EQ(valueOutputTester(conditions), accessDeniedOutput); 
}
{
    ValueOutputTester::TestConditions conditions = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
    EXPECT_EQ(valueOutputTester(conditions), accessDeniedOutput);
}
{
    ValueOutputTester::TestConditions conditions = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
    EXPECT_EQ(valueOutputTester(conditions), emptyOutput);
}
...
```

Can you recommend a better way of doing this?

Comment: If all those are boolean flags, you'll end up having between `2^(n-1)` and `2^n` tests, where `n` is the number of flags (but you probably already know that). I'm assuming you are testing all combinations due to the test where you use `(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)`. Instead of testing all combinations, you could test only each flag individually (`2n` tests at most), and then add relevant combinations. Also have code to generate your tests automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You might write a test helper method that lets you specify condition patterns and that generates all combinations that match the pattern, e.g. assuming -1 means 'either 0 or 1':

```
TestPattern pattern = {-1, -1, 1, -1, -1};
ExpectForPattern(pattern, emptyOutput);
```